# Having problems storing and displaying info in google firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a chatroom where the messages are stored in google firebase. I have not learned Javascript yet, but my schoolbook contains all the necessary Javascript code that I need for the task. The chatroom will have two inputs, one for username and one for a message, and a button to send the message. My problem is that whenever I try to send the message it won't store itself in the firebase and thus not be displayed. I apologize for the IDs and classes being in Norwegian, but I'm afraid that if I try to change it I will mess up something in the process.

```
<form id="skjema">
    <input type="text" id="inpAvsender" required placeholder="Brukernavn">
    <input type="text" id="inpMening" required placeholder="Melding">
    <button type="submit" class="button">Send</button>
</form>
<article id="txtMeldinger"></article>
// google firebase snippet here //
<script>
    let database = firebase.database();
    let meldinger = database.ref("meldinger");
    let skjema = document. 
    getElementById("skjema");
    let inpAvsender = document. 
    getElementById("inpAvsender");
    let inpMening = document. 
    getElementById("inpMening");
    let txtMeldinger = document.
    getElementById("txtMeldinger");
    function visMelding(snapshot) {
        let melding = snapshot.val();
        let meldingTekst ='<p>
            <b>${melding.avsender}:</b>
            <i>${melding.tekst}</i>
        </p>';
        txtMeldinger.innerHTML = txtMeldinger. 
        innerHTML + meldingTekst;
    }
    function regNyMelding(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var nyMelding = {
            avsender: inpAvsender.value,
            tekst: inpMening.value
        };
        meldinger.push(nyMelding);
        inpMening.value ="";
    }
    meldinger.on("child_added", visMelding);
    skjema.onsubmit = regNyMelding;
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any error in the browser console?

Comment: Not anything that I can spot. The way I understand it, it is supposed to add a p-element to the article, but the code is the same before as after posting the message. No information appears in the database either, as it has in prior tasks I've done.

Comment: Check your [Firebase Database Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/)

Comment: I've defined it as public by setting .read and .write as true

Comment: Found a fix! I had used the wrong apostrophe around the p-element ( ' vs. ` ).

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out :)